# django grappelli - disable on certain admin pages

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.6, django-grappelli

I have a problem of collation between grappelli and django-constance moduls (the saving  isn't working).

I'm using django-constance v.1.0.1 and cannot upgrade it because the new versions does not work with django 1.6 .

I want to disable grapelli on the constance specific page. How do I do that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for you to extend grappelli default change_view template with the specific html page you want to be shown ?